# .NET App.config connectionStrings local MS SQL Sever 2012 connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, windows-console

I tried quite many various of the connection strings  to get it working as follows:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add 
        name="CodeFirstTest" 
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
        connectionString="Server=ma\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true;Truested_Connection=true;"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Exception message:

> The type initializer for 'System.Data.Entity.Internal.AppConfig' threw an exception.

I'm not sure the exact SQL Server I installed. But by SQL Server Management Studio I can see as properties :-

[image]

`MA` is the name of he pc windows 8.1 installed. Also I tried `Server=.\SQLEXPRESS`. I get same exception.

Then tried the following:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="Default" 
         connectionString="metadata=res://*/Model1.csdl|res://*/Model1.ssdl|res://*/Model1.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MA\LOCALDB#57E60DE5;Database=test;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" 
         providerName="System.Data.EntityClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

I get exception:

> A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified).

Then modified `data source=ma\SQLEXPRESS`. Still get same error. How do I connect local db in .net / C#?

Comment: http://connectionstrings.com/

Comment: your second attempt should work if you use the correct `Data Source`, try setting it to `(localdb)\v11.0`

Comment: BTW, looks like you're using database first, why not let the designer do everything? You just need to do everything via designer.

Answer (score 0):

Change your connection string to be like below (notice the part `Server=ma\\SQLEXPRESS;`)

```
connectionString="Server=ma\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=true;Truested_Connection=true;"/>
```

Also notice the part in your connection string `Truested_Connection=true;`; it should be `Trusted_Connection=True;`. There is a spelling mistake.

Those keywords much match exactly else an exception would be thrown saying *unknown keywords*

Comment: this connection string works only for code-first. But looks like the OP's using database first workflow in which the actual connection string is included inside and set to `provider connection string`

Comment: @Hopeless, Umm that's not sure off but his connection string as well have a spelling mistake.